# jQuery addClass to parent and it's siblings

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I am trying to apply a class to an element's parent and it's siblings.  So far I have only been successful by applying two lines of jQuery which makes the end result apply in two stages looking pretty ugly.

```
<style type="text/css">
td.rostered {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
</style>

<table>
<tr class="flight_search">
    <td class="" style="width: 6%; text-align: left"><img id="525" class="roster" src="images/link_image.png" alt="Link Image"></td>
    <td class="" style="width: 7%">Option 1</td>
    <td class="" style="width: 24%">London -<strong>Paris</strong></td>
    <td class="" style="width: 25%">Dep: <strong>0355</strong>  Arr: 0615 (02:20)</td>
    <td class="" style="width: 30%">Boeing 767</td>
    <td class="" style="width: 8%"><a class="rego" href="#">ABCDE</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When the user clicks the image (with id="525") some ajax runs to assign that flight to the user's roster.  Then it returns with the id to run some jQuery to grey-out that row of the table, indicating that it is already rostered.

```
function set_rostered(id) {
//This line adds the class 'rostered' the siblins of the <td>
$("#" + id).parent().siblings().addClass('rostered');
//This line removes the id so the flight cannot be rostered again and adds the class to the parent <td> itself.
$("#" + id).attr('id', '').parent().addClass('rostered');
}
```

Is there a way I can combine these two lines of code to make the class apply to all elements (parent and it's siblings) at the same time?

Comment: Well, you could refactor your css to target `tr.rostered td` instead of `td.rostered`.  That would eliminate your first line.

Comment: jQuery version is 1.9.1.

Comment: Can you share CSS for the 'rostered' class?

Comment: edited OP with CSS.  Just a simple opacity atm, but I want to rework it once the effect is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it back (with the addBack() function):

```
$("#" + id).parent().siblings().addBack().addClass('rostered');
```

Comment: This works the same as the two line version (which I like, it's now one line instead of two).  But the effect still applies in two stages, first the text in the cells highlight and then the the <td>'s themselves about half a second later.

Comment: @Barbs "Highlight"?   Maybe you could make a fiddle that shows what this two stage effect is, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

$("#" + id).attr('id', '').parent().parent().children().addClass('rostered');